# Rails find model with text manipulation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails 3 environment using haml.

**Scenario**

we have an app whereby accounts have their own subdomain. the account may have been passed to us by a referral partner. the referral partner will also have their own account. Each account can store their own logo, including the partner. We want the end user accounts to display the partner logo on their login page.

**Approach**

So the way I went about this was to include a parameter with the login url, so that partners can have buttons on their own website that link to a page that displays their logo and our login form, such as

```
http://www.myapp.com/login?partner=bob
```

Then in the login form I look for the parameter, so

```
- if params[:partner].blank?
  = %img{src = > @our_logo}
- else
  - p = params[:partner]
  - a = Account.where(:full_domain => p}
  = %img{src = > a.logo}
```

Now this works great. however, the full_domain field contains what the name suggests, the full domain, so the code works as long as the login url is something like

```
http://www.myapp.com/login?partner=bob.myapp.com
```

I think this is nasty, and want something more like

```
http://www.myapp.com/login?partner=bob
```

which I think is neater.

**The problem**

What I need to be able to do is split out the first word of the full domain and find the account based on that. This code will certainly split it correctly...

```
a = Account.find(1)
a.full_domain.split('.').first
```

But I do not know how to use that when trying to find a record. So, for example, this failed

```
- a = Account.where((full_domain.split('.').first) => p).first
```

because full domain is not a symbol I think. This next attempt failed...

```
- a = Account.where((:full_domain.split('.').first) => p).first
```

because I don't think you can do a split on anything other than a string (sorry I am self taught and relatively new to both programming and ruby/rails!)

so finally I tried to convert it to a string like this...

```
- a = Account.where((:full_domain.to_s.split('.').first) => p).first
```

But this didn't work either, and I have a sneaky suspicion I am barking up the wrong tree.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

thanks in advance

G

Answer (score 1):

I might be thinking too simple, but isn't this what you want?

```
p = params[:partner]
a = Account.where(:full_domain, "#{p}.myapp.com").first
```

Comment: I would rather split the domain and then check it, as the development environments are setup with 'myapp.dev' but that was an interesting suggestion thanks!